# I want to send the request sent by postman to jmeter

Tags: jmeter, postman, web-api-testing

I want to changing  test tool from postman to jmeter.

Usual body format was raw-json, I did well without any problems.
But this case I should change form-data.

First, Postman confirmed response(return 200) and data check in db(maria-db).
But it continues to fail in jmeter.

Below is the data I saved in postman.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnULx.png)

I configured jmeter as shown in the picture, but it doesn't work.
Help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzGm7.png)

I changed config many time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9NZP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f2Eh.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a copy-paste issue, you're sending an incomplete request. Also it doesn't look like a [valid JSON](https://jsonlint.com/) to me.

You might also need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) and configure it to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of `application/json`

In general if your request can be successfully executed in Postman nothing prevents you from just recording it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

1. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/proxy/)

   [image]
2. [Import JMeter's certificate into Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)

   [image]
3. Run your request in Postman - JMeter will generate the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which can be replayed later on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it is not.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but it is

Comment: I'm not talking about changing postman's settings... I want to do a new test in jmeter that was conducted at postman.

Answer (score 0):

Your Postman example is not a raw\JSON request.

It's a form that has an JSON string in the value.

If needed, the header needs to be set to "multipart/form-data".

You add the elements to the request using the "Use multipart/form-data" option (as you have selected in your second screenshot) and then use the parameter tab (with the name being the key, and the value being the JSON) rather than the "Body Data" tab.

Here is my example, sending data to Postman Echo.

[image]

Using the JMeter proxy as a way of recording a Postman request is a decent way of working out what a request needs if you are not sure.

You can also use the code snippets options in Postman which will show you the code for different programming languages included CURL (which will show something like the following)

```
curl --location 'https://postman-echo.com/post' \
--header 'Cookie: sails.sid=s%3AsToeDnYuKjkLNh_xIGLN3-bQiTCuPt3j.5h3g7HutPvu2D2IYJ2peGzcT731EqhUhsp5cUdFrtpo' \
--form 'createRoom="{\"room\":{\"roomid\": 100,\"name\":\"test01\"}}"'
```

You can then import that into JMeter using "Import from cURL" under the tools menu.

[image]

This created an nearly identical request to the one I setup manually.

[image]

Comment: I changed my config 'body data'->'para meters'.
but it is same...not working

Comment: Can you show a copy of the request as it now looks?  Also what error is being produced?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the option of exporting from Postman as cURL using the code snippets, and then using the "Import from cURL" option in JMeter.  If it works in Postman, then it should work in JMeter.  If it doesn't, then you'll probably need to update your question and include some screenshots of the failing request. (From the View Results Tree).

Comment: Thank you for replies. I could import curl in Jmeter. And I started this test case. But request was fail.
This is view results tree in response data tab-response Body
{"timestamp":"2023-10-25T03:14:09.551","errorCode":"Unknown","message":"Content type 'text/plain;charset=US-ASCII' not supported","path":"/api/v-1/test/rooms/100/Class"}

Comment: first I added a headermanager (content-type : form-data).
second changed the http request>parameters>Content-Type (default:'text/plain'===>'form-data').
Neither was correct.

Comment: It's not "form-data".  It's "multipart/form-data".  Then check the request that is sent to see what Content-Header it sends.  I think Postman auto-defines this if its not set (and does a reasonably good job at it) but I suspect you have to be specific in JMeter.